How to fetch posts from a public Facebook group?
Here:
reading my facebook group posts via API, while on development mode
Facebook has allegedly removed the ability to access groups via:
GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed? amp;access_token=EAACEdEos0..."
And indeed I get the error:
{'error': {'message': '(#3) Missing Permission', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 3, 'fbtrace_id': 'A3CWyW2GZbZTn8auSEgbWLS'}}
When I try to access groups like this.
My question is, how is it possible today to access public groups and receive the posts from a group?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v19.0/group/feed#readperms - a group admin "installing" your app to the group is one of the important steps.
